# Create only the first fragment in a ViewPager when setting adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I'm want to make a ViewPager with TabLayout, 5 tabs and fragments in all. When the Activity is created, I only want the FragmentPagerAdapter to create the first (1st) tab, and then create the others when the user selects those tabs. setUserVisibleHint() does not work for my use case. I have also tried setting a dummy adapter first.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done with viewpager 
the default value of loaded screens outiside the viewpager is 1 and you can change it by calling

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

however the minimum value of the offscreenLimit is 1.
Hope it helps.